# How I can add error message in Laravel validate?

Tags: laravel, validation, controller, error-messaging

Help plz. "How add error user mistake in laravel" I want show JSON file - error $regex - reqular rules
I need get mistake on not correct sourceUrl

```
           $this->validate($request,[
            'title' => 'required|min:10|max:250', //work
            'subTitle' =>'sometimes|present|nullable|min:10|max:250', //work
            'message' => 'required|min:10',//work
            'recommendPic' => 'present|nullable', //work
            'pic' => 'required|sometimes', //file - check upload file,image need fix
            'sourceUrl' =>'required|regex:'.$regex,
       ],[
            'sourceUrl.regex:'.$regex=>'mistake',
       ]);
```

Comment: Is your issue that you want a custom error message, or that you don't know how to display the error message if your validation fails?

Comment: yes I dont know how show error message. I want if request sourceUrl  not answer on regular rule $regex I get mistake 'mistake'. Now I just get code 201 in postman but dont get message

Comment: I am assuming you're working with an API as you mentioned Postman, if not please clarify in your question.

Comment: You can do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62172324/4575350

Comment: yes API. On this moment problem with show error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return your failed validation messages, something like the following:

```
$validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required|min:10|max:250', //work
    'subTitle' =>'sometimes|present|nullable|min:10|max:250', //work
    'message' => 'required|min:10',//work
    'recommendPic' => 'present|nullable', //work
    'pic' => 'required|sometimes', //file - check upload file,image need fix
    'sourceUrl' =>'required|regex:'.$regex,
]);

// if validation fails
if ($validation->fails()) {
  return response()->json([
    'status' => 'failure',
    'errors' => $validation->errors()
  ], 400);
}

// validation passes
return response()->json(['status' => 'success'], 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

`'sourceUrl.regex:'.$regex=>'mistake',` is not valid PHP code.

It should be something like: `'sourceUrl.regex' => 'regex mistake'`

This redirects back with the error message `regex mistake`.

In your view you can print the message with `@error('sourceUrl') {{ $message }}@enderror`.